# Why use Pythons 'virtualenv' on Linux when one has 'chroot' (and union/overlay filesystems)?

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, chroot

First of all let me state that I am a proponent of generic software (in general ;-). I am no expert on Python, but it seems that the 'virtualenv' utility solves pretty much the same problem 'chroot' can help to solve - bootstrapping a directory tree that can be passed as root, thus effectively protecting the real directory tree, if needed.

Since I am no expert in Python as already mentioned, I wonder - what problem can virtualenv solve that chroot cannot? I mean, can't I just set up a nice fake root tree (possibly using union mounting), `chroot` into it, and do `pip install` a package I want in my new environment, and then play around within the bounds of my new environment, running python scripts and what not?

Am I missing something here?

#### Update:

Can't one install packages/modules locally in whatever application directory, I mean, without root privileges and subsequently without overwriting or adding files to `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`? It appears that this is what virtualenv does, however I think it has to symlink or otherwise provide a python interpreter for each environment one creates, does it not?

Comment: With chroot you have to wrap all your files and data, which you don't have to do with virtualenv. Also, virtualenv will run on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

> bootstrapping a directory tree that can be passed as root

That's not what virtualenv does, except (to some degree) for Python packages. It provides a place where these can be installed without replacing the rest of the filesystem. It also works without root privileges and it's portable as it needs no kernel support, unlike `chroot`, which (I presume) won't work on Windows.

> Can't one install packages/modules locally in whatever application directory

Yes, but virtualenv does one more thing, which is that it *disables* (by default at least) the system's Python package directories. That means you can test whether your package correctly installs all of its dependencies (you might have forgotten to list one because it's already installed on your system) and it allows installing different versions in case you need either newer or older versions. The ability to install older versions should not be overlooked because sometimes new versions of packages introduce bugs.

Comment: Thanks. Well, without kernel support, python wouldn't run on Linux at all, so I think kernel support is essential and a non-factor, at least for me. Same goes for Windows - I don't care for it in this context and it thus does not matter to me whether it supports `chroot` or not (which I know it doesn't). I am not advocating using chroot over virtualenv, not to anyone else, merely asking whether I can accomplish the desired result using the former instead of the latter?

Comment: @amn: I mean kernel support for `chroot`, of course -- it's a system call. But yes, you can replace virtualenv with chroot, it would be a lot more work and (for most use cases) overkill.